Using @DynamoDbFlattened in a field with variable subclasses
I'm working in a legacy database using SDKv1 for Dynamo. A table is modeled like:
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Product")
public class Product {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    private Metadata supplier;
}

where Metadata is an abstract class that can have different implementations.
class Metadata1 extends Metadata {
    private String attribute1
}

class Metadata2 extends Metadata {
    private String attribute2
}

I would like to include the fields of metadata as additional columns of my table (by flattening the metadata object). However, the @DynamoDBFlattened field forces me to declare in advance which fields to serialize, which I cannot do in this case.
Is there a way to include that metadata without declaring which fields to serialize? Note: migrating to v2 is not really feasible in this case.
I ried adding the attributes directly to the main schema, which works but reduces the overall flexibility. I also tried specifying all the possible arguments in the @DynamoDBFlattened annotation like:
  @DynamoDBFlattened(attributes = Array(
    new DynamoDBAttribute(mappedBy = "attribute1", attributeName="attribute1"),
    new DynamoDBAttribute(mappedBy = "attribute2", attributeName = "attribute2")
  )) def getMetadata


but that fails with an error:

DynamoDBMappingException: contains unknown flattened attribute(s)

